# Problema NuGet VisualStudio

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, asp, nuget

Estou com um problema.
Até ontem não estava, estava tudo normal. Hoje quando fui ativar uma migration, add ou update, está dando esse erro no console.

Enable-Migrations : Não é possível associar o argumento ao parâmetro 'Path' porque ele é nulo.
No linha:1 caractere:1
+ Enable-Migrations
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Enable-Migrations], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Enable-Migrations

Já fiz de tudo, reinstalei o pacote Entity, VisualStudio, reiniciei e nada. Apareceu de um dia para outro, alguem pode me ajudar?
Agradeço

Comment: Verifica se tem algum erro no código ou se alguma das entidades estão sem ID.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique se seu EntityFramework não foi atualizado para versão 6.3.0
Tive este mesmo problema e resolvi voltando para versão 6.2.0